# How do I setup Carthage to use my own Frameworks that are in private repository like Stash (Bitbucket)?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, carthage

I was wondering if there is something like [private pods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) in `Carthage`, I have a couple of frameworks and I'm currently using `git submodules`, I started using `Carthage` for a new project and is pretty nice but so far I just configured it to manage third party Frameworks dependencies. I've checked the [carthage documentation](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) but is not that clear on how to set it up.
Does `Carthage` work only with `Github` repos? Can it work with `Atlassian-Stash`(now `Bitbucket`)? If so how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So I finally found out how to setup Carthage with a `Atlassian-Bitbucket`

on the `Cartfile` i Just need to define the dependency origin which is the git repository

Enterprise git repository like `Atlassian-Stash(Bitbucket)`

```
git "https://stashRepo"
```

it also works with `ssh://`

Or local project

```
git "file:///directory/to/project" "branch"
```

**UPDATE**

Carthage has now added extra documentation on how the OGDL works in the 
[Cartfile](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/Documentation/Artifacts.md#cartfile)

Comment: git "file:///directory/to/project" "branch"

Comment: You must commit to your local branch as well. Uncommitted changes will not be built.

Answer (score 0):

### Solutions to Carthage Development Framework

To code a framework in a way similar to developing using CocoaPods Development Pods, there are solutions ready to used with Carthage.

### Solution 1 - The Local Path Way

This solution is quiet convenient than [alternative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067096/whats-the-equivalent-of-development-pods-under-carthage/54637582#54637582).

#### Step 1. Add local path into Cartfile

For example,

Add local path into Cartfile

```
git "PATH_TO_LOCAL_DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_SOURCE_ROOT_DIRECTORY" "BRANCH_NAME"
```

#### Step 2. Update Carthage dependency

For example,

Update Carthage dependency using Cartfile

```
$ carthage update $DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME --platform iOS --cache-builds --configuration Debug
```

To debug with breakpoints or to develop a framework in main project, add developing framework project reference `$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK).xcodeproj` into the main application, and build the main app in Xcode.

**Caution**

Remove developing overhead (such as the changes in `$(MAIN_APP_NAME).xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` due to the addition of developing framework project reference) before committing the changes to remote repo.

### [Solution 2 - The Symbolic Linking Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067096/whats-the-equivalent-of-development-pods-under-carthage/54637582#54637582)

**Tested Environment**

- Xcode 10.1
- macOS 10.13.6

Answer (score 0):

**Cartfile source location**

[[Dependency manager]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59257708/4770877)

`github` - GitHub repository

```
github "<owner>/<repo>" //GitHub.com
github "https://<path>" //GitHub Enterprise Server
```

`git` - Git repository

```
git "https://<path>" //remote
git "ssh://<command>" //ssh connection
git "file:///<path>" "<branch_name>" //local
```

`binary` - precompiled binary

```
binary "https://<path>.json" //remote
binary "file:///<path>.json" //local
```

Please note that `file:/` is used for local files which is useful for developing/debugging dependency. Do not forget to commit changes before using git

[[Local CocoaPods]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812997/4770877)
[[Local SPM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66715856/4770877)