# How can I debug carthage (owned) dependencies in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios-frameworks, carthage

I have an iOS application project with couple of private(owned) `carthage` dependencies, sometimes I'm in the need of debugging bugs or to know what is the code executed by certain methods.

I'd like to know if there is an easy way to setup the framework source code in `Carthage/Checkouts` using a run script, so that if I do a carthage update and run my app a can debug the frameworks source code without the need of adding sub projects.

Can this be done by including the debugging symbols in the framework build if so what would I need to do, to make it work?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067096/whats-the-equivalent-of-development-pods-under-carthage

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163412/how-do-i-setup-carthage-to-use-my-own-frameworks-that-are-in-private-repository

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to copy the dsym files as mentioned in [Carthage - Getting Started](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage)?

> With the debug information copied into the built products directory, Xcode will be able to symbolicate the stack trace whenever you stop at a breakpoint. This will also enable you to step through third-party code in the debugger.