# What's the equivalent of "development pods" under Carthage?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage

The teams developing frameworks for our iOS app are migrating from Cocoapods to Carthage.

Under Cocoapods, I could set up dependencies as "development pods". For example, instead of having the main app download a specific version of an `xyzzy` dependency, I could set up `xyzzy` as a development pod and point it to my local directory where I had checked out `xyzzy` from its Git repo. While I was working in the main app's project, any edits I'd do to `xyzzy`'s files would be made in that directory. This let me build and test changes immediately, and when I was ready to check them in, Git would find them in the `xyzzy` project's directory.

Under Carthage I haven't found a way to do this. I see http://allocinit.io/ios/debugging-carthage-dependencies/ which explains how to create symbolic links so that I can see the dependency source files to make debugging easier, but any edits I make to them are under the main application's `Carthage/Builds` directory.

How do I set up the equivalent of development pods under Carthage?

Comment: A summary of a successful implementation of the solution introduced in http://allocinit.io/ios/debugging-carthage-dependencies/ has been provided. It works for me :]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163412/how-do-i-setup-carthage-to-use-my-own-frameworks-that-are-in-private-repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Carthage **doesn't** have something similar to "development pods" yet.

But you could simulate "development pods" just following these steps:

**Steps:**

1. Add the .xcodeproj to your workspace
2. Remove all the dependencies you have in your project of the framework you added in step 1. (probably you may need to remove it from `Build Phases -> Run Script -> Input Files` too )
3. Go to `General` tab of the target you want to run, add the framework under `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` (it is going to take the one added from the .xcoproj)
4. (optional) you may need to run `carthage bootstrap` in the framework's repo you want to add locally.

That's it.

After that you will be able to run your project and update framework's code in the same workspace.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Just a note - for step 2, in my project, I had to remove the dependency's framework from the Build Phases / Run Script / Input Files section for `carthage copy-frameworks`.

Comment: Additionally, a lesson I just learned the hard way: make sure you apply steps 2-3 to *each build target*. Otherwise, if you switch to a different target that for which haven't changed the build settings, the code you're looking at will not be the code that's being run.

Answer (score 0):

This works just as well as development pods for me, as of Xcode 8.3.3 and Carthage 0.24.0:

1. In app path, `rm -rf Carthage`
2. Point at the appropriate branch or tag in `Cartfile`
3. `carthage update --use-submodules` (generates `.gitmodules` and clones repo into `Carthage/Checkouts`)
4. In Xcode under project -> Build Phases -> Run Script, comment out the line that ends with `carthage update --cache-builds` if present.
5. Change to the General tab and remove the lib from Embedded Binaries
6. Right-click project, Add Files to app..., add lib from `Carthage/Checkouts`
7. Under project -> General, re-add the library, choosing the one you added in the previous step.

App should now build with the local lib. Make sure that your `.gitignore` has `Carthage/{Build,Checkouts}` and `.gitmodules`.

Comment: This would clear *all* your Carthage dependencies, where most likely one will want to have only 1 or a few pods in "development mode". With CocoaPods you can specify the local path for individual pods.

Comment: Oops! You're totally right. I still only had 1 Carthage lib in that project and didn't consider this.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a summary of a *successful* implementation of the solution introduced [here](http://allocinit.io/ios/debugging-carthage-dependencies/).

A cleaner solution is [using local paths for dependencies in Cartfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163412/how-do-i-setup-carthage-to-use-my-own-frameworks-that-are-in-private-repository/54645387#54645387).

### Environment

- Xcode 10.1
- macOS 10.13.6

### Step 1.  Symbolic linking

**1.1**   Change `$(SRCROOT_MAIN)/Carthage/Checkouts/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME)` directory to a symbolic link pointing to source root directory of your developing framework `$(SRCROOT_DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK)`, where `$(SRCROOT_MAIN)` is source root directory of your main app. Backup existing directories before this change.

This linking enables version-controlled changes in your developing framework.

Syntax when using `ln` utility,

```
$ ln -s "$SRCROOT_DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK" "$SRCROOT_MAIN/Carthage/Checkouts/$DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME"
```

**1.2**   Change `$(SRCROOT_DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK)/Carthage/Build` directory in your framework to a symbolic link pointing to `$(SRCROOT_MAIN)/Carthage/Build` directory. Backup existing directories before this change.

This linking enables access to all frameworks built by Carthage from both your developing framework and your main app.

Syntax when using `ln` utility,

```
$ ln -s "$SRCROOT_MAIN/Carthage/Build" "$SRCROOT_DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK/Carthage/Build"
```

### Step 2.  Framework Replacement

**2.1**   Remove your developing framework in `Xcode > YOUR_MAIN_APP > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries` (that is, the one located in `$(SRCROOT_MAIN)/Carthage/Build/iOS`).

**2.2**   Add `$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).xcodeproj` (found in directory pointed by `$(SRCROOT_MAIN)/Carthage/Checkouts/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME)` symbolic link) into your main app

**2.3**   Build the developing framework product for device and simulator

**2.4**   Add the new developing framework auto-detected by Xcode in `Xcode > YOUR_MAIN_APP > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

**2.5**   Add `$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` as a target dependency by adding `$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` in `Xcode > YOUR_MAIN_APP > Build Phases > Target Dependencies`.

**2.6**   Copy `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` by adding a new input file `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` and a new output file `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/$(DEVELOPING_FRAMEWORK_NAME).framework` in `Xcode > YOUR_MAIN_APP > Build Phases > Run Script of Carthage Embed Framework`.

### Reference

```
Debugging Carthage Dependencies
https://allocinit.io/ios/debugging-carthage-dependencies/

Build Setting Reference
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html
```