# Debugging (owned) Framework when using Carthage

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, frameworks, carthage

I am in the process of developing my own Swift framework to be used privately between two of my applications. I am using Carthage to manage that and other dependencies.

I finally got through developing the framework and hooking it up to one of my apps and, not surprisingly, the app crashes in the new framework code.

I would like to debug the framework code. I've looked at some articles that talk about:

1. Copying the dsym files and
2. Compiling with debugging information.

Unfortunately, the articles leave out a lot of details (and I'm not a seasoned enough iOS developer or Carthage user to implicitly know them).

Can someone provide a recipe on how to configure the app such that the private framework code is not optimized and I can step into the framework code from the hosting application?

Thanks
Peter...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067096/whats-the-equivalent-of-development-pods-under-carthage

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163412/how-do-i-setup-carthage-to-use-my-own-frameworks-that-are-in-private-repository

Answer (score 10):

Here are two options.

#### 1. Debug framework within main project

Follow step 4 of the [Carthage guide](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos) and then you should be able to step through and debug your private framework.

> With the debug information copied into the built products directory, Xcode will be able to symbolicate the stack trace whenever you stop at a breakpoint. This will also enable you to step through third-party code in the debugger.

#### 2. Modify framework within main project

1. Clone the private framework source locally.
2. Drag the framework's `.xcodeproj` into your main project. (Do not have both projects open in Xcode).
3. remove crthage entry form `carthageInput.xcfilelist & carthageOutput.xcfilelist`
4. remove the framework from `project -> target -> general -> frameworks libraries and embedded content` then add it using the `+` sign from the dragged project. then you will see beside the framework name `Embed & sign`

Now you can develop on your private framework and test them all within your main project. Once done

1. Remove reference to framework `.xcodeproj` from main project.
2. Create a new release of your framework.
3. Update main project to use newer version using standard `carthage update`

Comment: If I follow #2 above how do I get XCode to use the framework within instead of the one added by carthage? @ajmccall

Comment: @cbartel I think you have to remove the reference of the Carthage framework and use the one generated from the `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: There's a few more steps for 2. In my case I had to make sure I dragged my frameworks .xcodeproj within the main apps project. Then after removing the dependencies on the Carthage imported version I could add the existing framework as a build dependency in the main projects Build Dependencies -> Target Dependencies.  Clean build and all good.